# Changing the value of an object based on the time of day?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a project that is a player attendance log. Every player is an object I created using class syntax and in theory the values of the object should change based on the time of day. This doesn't work because the values are either true or false regardless of what time of day it is. What is going wrong and how can I fix it? here's a link to my project https://github.com/bloodwolf616/project9

Problem code:

```
const today = new Date();
const hour = today.getHours();
const second = today.getSeconds();

for (let i = 0; i < attendance.length; i++){

    if (hour > 10 && hour < 20) {
        if(player1 && player2 && player3 && player4) {attendance[i]._online = true;}
    } else {
        attendance[i]._online = false;
    }

    if (second > 20 || second < 40) {
        if(error) {
            attendance[i]._online = true;}
    } else {
        attendance[i]._online = false;
    }
```

Comment: That's because you first set attendance[i]._online based on Hour, and then again reasign the very same based on second value. I mean no matter what hours are, the second related criteria makes the attendance[i]._online = false (or, somethis to true)

Comment: Not sure what you doing in second if statement but it will be always true (second > 20 || second < 40), as you need && not || there. And if there is no error it will always set attendance[i]._online to false. Just debug and check how it working run-time.